# NiFi: How to combine data from many files into one file

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I  want to get more than 20,000 `flowfile`'s from hdfs and reunite them into one `flowfile`.

I  want  to  get  data  from  these  files  (they are in `xml` format) and  input it into variable named *content*, then when I finish this process I want  to serilize `xml` in a way that all this data will be enrolled inside  `<data>...</data>` tag)

Is it possible to fulfil this task by NiFi processors or I will have to use  groovy code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the standard NiFi build. You can of course create your own NiFi processor to do this but it may be a bit overkill.

You will have to use groovy. What I suggest doing is the following:

1) Read in the files from the HDFS folder

2) Process these files and get the data out of the files that you want.

3) If you're wanting to produce a single xml file: Write straight to an XML file using a `fileoutputstream` as you're processing each file and grabbing the information. This could be done locally and then once finished it could be moved back to HDFS/a folder that is under watch by NiFi to continue your pipeline.

Note: There *is* a processor that can concatenate files (or 'reunite' as you said) - the `MergeContent` processor. This is perhaps a bit moot in your case though.